# Override the style of react datepicker popper className

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

Im trying to override the margin-top style of react-datepicker-popper:

```
.react-datepicker-popper[data-placement^="bottom"] {
    margin-top: 10px;
```

So in my main.scss file i'm writing

```
.react-datepicker-popper[data-placement^="bottom"] {
  margin-top: -10px !important;
}
```

but it does not seem to work. Any ideas why?

Comment: When I try this, it works on the spot: https://codesandbox.io/s/wowqj99m28 Are you sure your SCSS is compiled to CSS properly?

Comment: No it's not working..i'm beggining to desperate :P

Comment: Can you put your attempt online, live, so we can take a look?